# Three.js Plane Geometry Animation

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

Im working on this thing, its basically a really simple "landscape" in 3D, its a first thing I am doing with three.js so I am losing my mind. I tried many different things but nothing works, I only once managed to crash the browser. This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var vertexHeight = 900;
var vertexHeightUpdated = 1100;
var planeDefinition = 30;
var planeSize = 25000;

var container = document.getElementById('head_threejs');
var fog = new THREE.Fog(0x000000, 1000, 17000);
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(65, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,1, 20000)

camera.position.z = 5500;

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(planeSize, planeSize, planeDefinition, planeDefinition);
geometry.dynamic = true;
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xffffff, specular: 0xdddddd, shininess: 30, shading: THREE.FlatShading});

var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
plane.rotation.x -=1;

scene.add( plane );
scene.fog = fog;

  var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x1a1a1a);
  scene.add( ambientLight );

  var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xdfe8ef, 0.10);
  dirLight.position.set(3, 5, 1);
  scene.add( dirLight );


var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

updatePlane();

 function updatePlane() {
   for (var i = 0; i < plane.geometry.vertices.length; i++)
   {
     plane.geometry.vertices[i].z += Math.random()*vertexHeight     -vertexHeight;
   }
 };

 function animateShit(){
   plane.geometry.vertices[1].z+=.01;
   plane.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate=true;
 }


render();

        function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame( render );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }


  window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }
});
```

So .. there is a little leftover of my last animation try-out (I just wanted to see if it changes somehow), more like last-resort-sigh-kill-me thing. I even tried a tweening library for three.js but I didnt figure out how would I use it in this scenario.

What I wanna do is, have the planes vertices (or vertexes?) move up and down "randomly" creating a "breathing" effect of the "landscape". Hopefully that is understandable.

Id really appreciate at least a nudge in the right direction, I think Im just thinking about it in a wrong way or I maybe have some other problems in my present code.

**EDIT:**
to clarify what was the last thing I tried:

I tried using the tween.js library and adding something like this

```
var vertexHeightUpdate = 1100;
var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(vertexHeight).to(vertexHeightUpdate, 5000);

tween.onUpdate(function(){
vertexHeight = vertexHeightUpdate;
});

tween.start();
```

And then adding tween.update(); to the render segment of my code.

**EDIT2:**

**I got it moving!** But its still far away from what I want..

```
updateVerts();

function updateVerts() {
for (var i = 0; i < plane.geometry.vertices.length; i++)
{
 plane.geometry.vertices[i].z += Math.random()*planeDefinition -(planeDefinition/2);
}
plane.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
};
```

and adding updateVerts(); to my render loop.

Now this makes my plane "shiver".. and get bigger over time, not sure why. It is very close to what I am imagining but now Im stuck again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jan I just stumbled into your question.

I see you have a problem updating/refreshing the scene. But you are doing a lot of other things at the same time so just stick to creating a [PlaneGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/PlaneGeometry) (three.js) in a canvas window with a button to update the scene moving just 1 vertex and add all other things later.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("START");

  function render() {
      requestAnimationFrame( render );
      renderer.render( scene, camera );
  }

  function refresh() {
    console.log("refresh");
    plane.geometry.vertices[0].z =  50;
    plane.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  }

  var w = 600;
  var h = 400;

  var button = document.createElement("input");
  button.type = "button";
  button.value = "REFRESH SCENE";
  button.onclick = function(){refresh()};
  document.body.appendChild(button);

  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, w / h, 0.1, 1000 );

  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize( w, h );
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 300, 168, 300 , 168 );
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
  var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  scene.add( plane );

  camera.position.set(200,200,200);
  camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);
  camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(50,0,0));
  scene.add( camera );

  render();

});
```

This will create a button and a canvas window with a yellow PlaneGeometry. If you click the button `plane.geometry.vertices[0]` will move to a z location of 50 (from 0) and is updated/refreshed in the canvas window. (far right corner of the PlaneGeometry)

From here it is just a minor step to manipulate all vertex points. (and create a real breathing sense by transforming the plane in time with a beautiful algorithm not just shaking it in a random way).

With:

```
var ray = new THREE.Ray(camera.position, vector.subSelf(camera.position).normalize()),intersects    = ray.intersectObject(plane);
```

you can also manipulate a vertex by clicking on the PlaneGeometry on the canvas and computing all kinds of reactions on the other vertices in time.

I hope this helps =^)

Comment: This throws "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"